# multiple select, and math operations in mysql

Tags: mysql

I've been searching and trying a lot for this query but I didn't get the correct results, I still a students and still exploring mysql queries.
I have this two table that is not related to each other, the stocks table and order_details table.
Where in the stocks was the records of the stocks coming in the product id, quantity and the date received or added while the order details where the details of the order, where there is the product and quantity of the order.

Now I want to select all the quantity of the product from the stocks and in the order details and then subtract the total quantity of the stocks and the total quantity of order details.

```
    select
 (Select  sum(stocks.quantity) as sq from  stocks  group by product_id)
 - 
(Select sum(order_details.quantity) as oq from order_details group by product_id) as available_quantity;
```

I have this query but it shows a error message ***"Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row"***

And then I have this query but only returns one column

```
     select 
          (Select sum(stocks.quantity) as sq from  stocks where stocks.product_id="2" group by product_id) - 
(Select sum(order_details.quantity) as oq from order_details where  order_details.product_id="2" group by product_id) as available_quantity ;
```

And then after substracting , add a condition where fetch only the avaialable_quantity that is morethan or equals to 1.

my tables
CREATE TABLE `stocks` (
  `stock_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_added` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`stock_id`),
  KEY `prod_fk_idx` (`product_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `prod_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`prod_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE `order_details` (
  `order_details_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_details_id`)
);

Comment: Learn how to debug your own code.  It's part of programmer's job!!!  Have you tried running only you inner queries to check if you get more than one row or not???  If you do, then it's a good place to start fixing.

Comment: I am sorry @Eric if I can't debug my own code because I am just a newbie and a student still learning this.

Comment: can you show us your table structures? `show create table stocks` and `show create table order_details`. also, do you have a table that lists just the products?

Comment: @maineshar That's a BS excuse.  How do you think newbie fix their code before internet age???  They learn to debug their code.

Comment: @mpen I edited my question.